# Запуск контейнеров в Kubernetes после конвертации конфига из docker compose с помощью kompose падает с ошибкой not a directory

Tags: docker-compose, kubernetes

Помогите начинающему кубернетеру, пожалуйста.
Пытаюсь с помощью тулзы kompose переконфигурировать docker compose файл в конфиги для kubernetes, согласно официальной инструкции: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/

Сам перевод конфига выполняется без проблем, а вот при попытке запустить полученное при помощи kubectl apply, контейнеры падают со следующей ошибкой:
[image: ошибка]

Смысл ошибки я понимаю, не может выполнить маунт, так как это файл, а не директория. А вот почему не может, уже понять не могу. Насколько я знаю, примаунтить файлы конфиг кубернетса позволяет. Это kompose криво конвертацию делает или что?

В исходном docker-compose.yml файле проблемное место выглядит так:
[image: docker_compose]

В prometheus-deployment.yaml после конвертации с помощью kompose, получается следующее:
[image: pr_dep_1]

[image: pr_dep_2]

Есть предположение, что prometheus.yml пытается примаунтить, как тип persistentVolume и в этом проблема, но это только предположение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и что надо исправить?